# What React Library can I use for a drop down description

Tags: web-apps

As a precursor, I am not looking for a drop-down menu. Googling anything related to React and Drop-down will give you a plethora of libraries that have drop-down menus but what I am looking for is a drop-down description React library for a FAQ section of a website.

The functionality I am looking for is on clicking the question box display text-answer underneath and clicking again or on a different one, hide the text again.

Here is a 7-second video displaying the interaction I am trying to describe:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cH-jrLPQBF4&feature=youtu.be